# Evaluate the function $f(x)=\frac{x^2+3e^x}{e^{2x}}$ using Maclaurin series

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

$$x^2+3e^x=x^2+3\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}+O(x^n)=x^2+3\left(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+O\left(x^2\right)\right)$$
$$e^{2x}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2x)^n}{n!}+O\left(x^{n+1}\right)=1+2x+2x^2+O\left(x^3\right)$$

$$\frac{x^2+3e^x}{e^{2x}}=\frac{\frac{5}{2}x^2+3x+3+O\left(x^2\right)}{2x^2+2x+1+O\left(x^3\right)}$$

How to divide this expression?

Comment: Long division could be simple (taking more terms in top and bottom)..

Comment: @Claude Leibovici  Lond division gives $\frac{5}{2}x^2+3x+\frac{17}{4}+O\left(x^3 \right)$. How to check if this is correct for $f(x)$?

Comment: You have some mistakes in the division : you have to divide $3+3x+\frac 52x^2$ by $1+2x+2x^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps simpler, in the sense that it avoids the long division, is the following:

$$x^2 e^{-2x} = x^2 \sum_{k \ge 0} \frac{(-2)^k}{k!} x^k = \sum_{k\ge 2} \frac{(-2)^{k-2}}{(k-2)!} x^k$$

$$3e^{-x} = \sum_{k\ge 0} 3\frac{(-1)^k}{k!} x^k$$

Consequently,

$$f(x) = 3 -3x + \sum_{k\ge 2} (-1)^k \left(\frac{3}{k!} + \frac{2^{k-2}}{(k-2)!}\right) x^k$$

You can simplify the expression in the parenthesis, and truncate as required.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the fact that, for $-1<t<1$, $$\frac{1}{1+t}=1-t+t^2-t^3+t^4+\cdots+(-t)^n+\cdots$$

And substitute $t=2x^2+2x$ (or the suitable part of the expansion of $e^{2x}-1$, according ot the precision you want in the approximation).